# Scroll view не работает, если view выше или ниже его пустые в сториборд

Tags: ios, swift

Проблема такая. У меня в контроллере в сториборде иерархия вьюшек: view -> scrollview -> view . Если хотя бы на 1 из них нет дополнительного сабвью (например кнопки, почему то с лейблом это не работает?!) - после старта приложения скрол не будет работать, пока я не переверну устройство. После этого все работает нормально (viewDidLayoutSubviews() вызывается 2жды для корректной работы ?!). Если на 1 из вьюх есть (и я не удаляю в disp) сабвью, даже без constraints - все скролится нормально с момента старта программы. 
Примерный код моего контроллера:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView! //Верхняя вьюшка
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    disp()
 }
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: actualsize)
}
var actualsize : CGFloat = 0
func disp(var width: CGFloat){
    self.myView.subviews.map({$0.removeFromSuperview()})
//create some subviews here
actualsize = 100500
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Чудеса :), посмотрите в дебаге иерархию ваших представлений, возможно, всё не совсем так как вы думаете.

Comment: Да нет, вроде все так) Я отписался в баг репорт эпл и сделал для них проект заново. Глюк остался :)

Comment: А можно его где-нить на git увидеть? Интересно.

Comment: Да, пожалуйста. https://github.com/yota9/scrollviewExmplFailed
In example project you will find 2 controllers - works and not working. In works you can place button on the above view with the same result. But if you change it to label it won't work.

Comment: Ошибка проявляется только в iOs 8, проверил в 7 - все работает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

В приведённом проекте ничего и не должно скролироваться, так как UIScrollView [определяет](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)  contentSize по распоркам, которые вы добавили.
Если изменить распорки, то всё начинает работать как ожидается:

[image: Правильное расположение распорок]

При этом важным моментом вляется то, что правая и нижняя распорки удаляются в Runtime а размер дочернего представления связан с главным представлением UIViewController.

Теперь что касается того, почему работает с кнопкой, а без кнопки нет. Здесь могу только предположить, что при добавлении кнопки, она дополнительно уведомляет родительское представление о том, что внутри изменилось расположение элементов и соответсвенно вызывается didLayout...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но ведь мы же говорим об условных распорках скроллью, вы сами говорите, что в рантайме их нет, они показывают расположение скрола на экраэне. А сам скролл задается contentsize'ом. + Ко всему никаких проблем iOs 7 с такой конфигурацией не испытывает... Попробовал задавать только верхнюю и боковую константы + горизонтальное и вертикальное расположение-без результатно. PS если менять константу во время выполнения - все равно не работает.

Comment: Не совсем так, предполагаю, что в iOs 8 ,  layoutSubviews в scrollView вызывается после того как у родительской View вызывается layoutSubviews в котором для  scrollView вычисляется frame. Далее ScrollView вызывает у себя setNeedsLayout и ждёт когда runtime вызовет layoutSubviews. В методе ScrollView LayoutSubviews, ScrollView проверяет внутренние распорки для дочерних элеметнтов и устанавливает contentSize.

Comment: Скорее всего на iOs 7 layoutSubview у scrollView вызывается синхронно и поэтому ваш вызов перетирает установленное значение для ContentSize. Но повторяю, в приведённом проекте (на git), ничего и не должно скролится, так как размер внутренней view жёстко привязан к внутренним размерам scrollView.

Comment: Видимо, добавление ещё одной View как-то влияет на внутреннюю последовательность  вызовов (попробуйте, если интересно, наследовать UIView, UIScrollView  и перегрузите соответсвующие методы).

Comment: Распорки редко бывают условные, для того чтобы они стали условными, они должны удаляться в Runtime (для этого нужно установить checkBox в InterfaceBuilder)